# How to update an alarm time in calendar when events are updated?

Tags: java, android, calendar, alarm

I'm trying to update the alarm time that is set when calendar events are inserted.
I've searched through net and got a final that the event alarm  can be cancelled and the particular event alone can be updated with new time for alarm. I'm struck out here how to implement it. Any help is highly appreciated and thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to be messing with the calendar. It's not part of the Android API, and even if there exists a back door, it is highly discuraged to use it.

Even if  you want a "Snooze" functionality, you won't be able to capture the Intent that causes the alarm to go off, as this is not an API standard, and may be fired targeting a specific receiver class.

You can however access and modify the calendar entries through the [Google Data API](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide.html), but that's a whole different story.

Comment: You are right, but by updating calendar event time, the alarm time cannot be synchronized right?

Comment: Since both Calendar and Alarm are different applications, Though it is not the best idea to use of it, the requirements are based only on alarm being updated when calendar event updated with new time.

Comment: Perhaps I missunderstood your question. I thought that you were talking about updating the notifications associated with the Calendar entries.
You're right, AlarmClock app and Calendar App are two different things. But neither of them is part of the Android API. I didn't check the source but I have a strong feeling, that the Calendar app doesn't use the AlarmClock app for notifications.

Comment: Ya, By default, Calendar is using its own notification to notify the user. But i have initiated the alarmmanager for each event that the calendar notification+ alarm notification notifies the user. Now after your confirmation, it is felt that it is not possible for updating the alarm notification when calendar event is updated with new time. Is it right?